# What is the number of balloons a person can inflate in $T$ seconds?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Bob can inflate a balloon in $t$ seconds if he inflates $z$ balloons, he rests for $y$ seconds. What is the number of balloons he can inflate in $T$ seconds.

It's clear that he can inflate $\frac{T}{t}$ rounded down without rest. I don't know how to solve this if Bob rests after inflating $z$ balloons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider block of time of length $zt+y$, in that period of time, $z$ balloons are inflated.

Let $$T=q(zt+y)+r, 0\le r < zt+y$$

In $q(zt+y)$ time, we have $qz$ balloons inflated.

For the remaining time, $r$, we have a maximum of $z$ balloons, for the remaining time $\lfloor \frac{r}{t} \rfloor$ balloons can be created.

That is we have a total of $$qz + \min\left(z, \left\lfloor \frac{r}t\right\rfloor\right)$$

where $q = \left \lfloor \frac{T}{zt+y} \right\rfloor $ and $r=T-q(zt+y)$.

Comment: I think it should be $qz$, shouldn't it?

Comment: ah, yes, you are right.